# Docker: posix_spawnp(). Permission denied

Tags: docker, centos8

I'm trying to use Docker to run an executable ELF binary within a RockyLinux8 environment that uses the posix_spawnp() function in C++. Outside of the Docker container this works as expected and I know Docker doesn't like processes running freely, so I'm guessing this might be it because of my experience trying to run two services. Is this another case of this or is there something else happening?

Code clarification:
`posix_spawnp(PROCESS_ID,PROCESS_NAME, NULL, NULL, argv.data(), environ)`

**Testing**

I just ran a test where a C++ program executed **echo "Hello World"** using posix_spawnp inside a Docker container as an entrypoint, no errors. Appears to be something a tad deeper. Will update this post with what I find.

Comment: Can you use the more traditional fork(2)/execve(2)?  Do you have a [mcve]?  What's going wrong?  There's no technical reason you can't start a subprocess, but you do need to make sure you wait(2) for it to finish (and you will also need to wait(2) for its children, if it orphans them).

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by following a suggestion on another post where exec permissions were required, which turns out the mystery script being executed was a shell script and not a binary file. Ended up added executive permissions on the file and it worked.